# Representing pencils with vector bundle maps

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $G = \mathbb{G}(1, 3) = G(2, 4)$ and $\pi : S \longrightarrow G$ be the universal bundle on $G$ with $\pi^{-1}(\Lambda) = [\Lambda]$ for each $\Lambda \in G$.

In Exercise C-4 on p. 104 of "Geometry of Algebraic Curves (Vol. I)", it is stated that a general pencil of quartic surfaces $\{F_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{P}^1}$ is represented as a vector bundle map $\mathcal{O}^{\oplus 2} \longrightarrow \text{Sym}^4 S^*$.

I have some idea of how to get a similar map, but it's from $\mathcal{O}^{\oplus n}$ for some other $n$ and I'm not sure why it comes from the pencil.

Let $N$ be the number of monomials of degree $d$ in $n + 1$ variables and consider a pencil of degree $d$ hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^n$ parametrized by $\mathbb{P}^1$. Set $G = \mathbb{G}(1, n)$ and define $S$ analogously. One way to get a map from $\mathcal{O}^{\oplus N} \longrightarrow \text{Sym}^4 S^*$ is to use the map induced by the restriction of a degree $d$ polynomial in $x_0, \ldots, x_n$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$ to $\Lambda \in \mathbb{G}(1, n)$ (note: $\Lambda \cong \mathbb{P}^1$). However, I don't think $N = 2$ if $n = 3$ and $d = 4$ and I don't see how this map would come from a pencil.

What would be the right way to think about the map $\mathcal{O}^{\oplus 2} \longrightarrow \text{Sym}^4 S^*$ and similar maps representing pencils of hypersurfaces?

Answer (score 1):

[**Marked Community Wiki since I didn't come up with this. This question used to be cross-posted to MO and I was pointed towards an answer there. It was the case that this question was not appropriate for that platform.**]

This was actually very simple. First, a pencil is defined by two polynomials. This gives us $\mathcal{O}^{\oplus 2}$. Secondly, we have $Hom(\mathcal{O}_X, \mathcal{F}) \cong H^0(X, \mathcal{F})$ for a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on a scheme $X$. Since $H^0(G, \text{Sym}^4 S^*) = H^0(\mathbb{P}^3, \mathcal{O}(4))$, this is just a pair of homogeneous degree $4$ polynomials in $x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3$.

Other pencils coming from hypersurfaces can be considered in the same way.